# Ionic Native Plugin Text To Speech

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework

I have a very simple question to ask. I want to speak other language ,then just the default en-US. I check with the official pagehttps://ionicframework.com/docs/native/text-to-speech/#TTSOptions, but i don't really have clue how to apply it inside the usage code.

Usage:

```
import { TextToSpeech } from '@ionic-native/text-to-speech';

constructor(private tts: TextToSpeech) { }

...

this.tts.speak('Hello World')
  .then(() => console.log('Success'))
  .catch((reason: any) => console.log(reason));
```

Here's the option i want to add in to the usage code.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the TTSOptions to the speak() function:

```
this.tts.speak({
  text: "Hello world",
  locale: "en-US" // Pass any locale you want here.
}).then(() => console.log('Success'))
  .catch((reason: any) => console.log(reason));
```